# Convert jpg images to blob and store it in a .sql file

Tags: php, python, mysql, jpeg

I store jpg images into a mysql database.

I use the BLOB type to store the jpg images in the mysql database.

I use mysqldump to generate a .sql file.

I use the .sql file as backup and restore the database.

How can I convert a jpg directly to a .sql file?

I have tried this python code:

```
import os

import base64

archivo_destino = ".\\portada_sql\\archivo.sql"

imagen_origen = ".\\libros_nuevos_jpg\\03000\\000.jpg"

archivo = open(archivo_destino, 'w')

imageFile = open(imagen_origen, "rb") 

mi_blob = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

archivo.write("INSERT INTO libro_portada VALUES ('"+mi_blob+"');")

archivo.close()
```

But it does not work.

It is possible to create a sql file with a image stored as blob usign python?

I try to avoid:

- upload the jpg to the server
- import jpg to mysql
- export mysql to .sql file

I want to generate directly the .sql file.

It is possible?

1.
Magnus:
I mentioned php  because I can use php too, if this is possible with php.

2.
Eric:
From the python code mentioned above, I get:

INSERT INTO libro_portada VALUES ('b'/9j/4RivRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAE'');

From mysqldump I get:

INSERT INTO `libro_portada` VALUES ('ÿ\؀ÿ\ကJExif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\Z\0\0\0\0\0\0\0b');

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'it does not work'? Are you getting any exceptions, does it silently fail? Please create a [mcve] so it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: 1. 
Magnus Eriksson:
I am trying to do it with python.. But, can it be done with php?

2.
This is a mysqldump result:

When i run my code I get this:

Comment: You can probably to it with most languages (depending on the actual result you're  expecting), so you need to pick the language you want help with. The more you narrow down your question, the better.

Comment: An overlooked question: *why* are you storing your images in your database, instead of "as images on a filesystem", storing the metadata in the DB only?

Comment: Good lord, do not do *any* of this. Not to mention that every individual layer of your problem is an ugly hack, and each ugly hack is performed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is insane to store files in mysql, but I only work as a monkey code in this project.

Finally i used MYSQL LOAD_FILE() function

I uploaded my jpgs to the server and imported to mysql using: MYSQL LOAD_FILE()

There are thoundsands of files to uplodad, so I created a python script to create the sql code and store it in sql file.

```
# coding=utf-8
#! python3
# crea el comando mysql para importar los archivos .jpg a mysql
# para cada libro crea un archivo sql
# para cada archivo crea un comando insert
# INSERT INTO  archivo  SET libro_fk =,orden =,nombre =,archivo =,mime_type ="image/jpeg",numero_pagina =,libro_completo =0;

import os


libros = [
"K0LEM",
"K3J2S"
]


ids = [

"2390",
"2399"
]




total = len(libros)

#para cada libro...
for i in range(total):
    #crearemos un archivo sql para cada libro
    archivo_destino = ".\\archivos_sql\\" + ids[i] + ".sql"
    archivo = open(archivo_destino, 'w')
    carpeta_a_explorar = ".\\libros_nuevos_jpg\\" + libros[i] + "\\"
    archivos = os.listdir(carpeta_a_explorar)
    #crear una lista con los archivos
    archivos.sort()
    #ordena la lista
    cuantos_archivos = len(archivos)
    #cuantos archivos
    #
    # para cada archivo encontrado se creara un insert...
    #
    for jpg_file in range(cuantos_archivos):
        archivo.write("INSERT INTO  archivo  SET libro_fk ="+ ids[i] +",orden = "+str(jpg_file)+",nombre ='"+ archivos[jpg_file] +"',archivo = LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/"+ libros[i] +"/"+ archivos[jpg_file] +"'),mime_type ='image/jpeg',numero_pagina = "+str(jpg_file)+",libro_completo =0;")
        archivo.write("\n")
    archivo.close()
```

The result is a sql file with an insert command per line using MYSQL LOAD_FILE()

```
INSERT INTO  archivo  SET libro_fk =2390,orden = 0,nombre ='000.jpg',archivo = LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/K0LEM/000.jpg'),mime_type ='image/jpeg',numero_pagina = 0,libro_completo =0;
INSERT INTO  archivo  SET libro_fk =2390,orden = 1,nombre ='001.jpg',archivo = LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/K0LEM/001.jpg'),mime_type ='image/jpeg',numero_pagina = 1,libro_completo =0;
INSERT INTO  archivo  SET libro_fk =2390,orden = 2,nombre ='002.jpg',archivo = LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/K0LEM/002.jpg'),mime_type ='image/jpeg',numero_pagina = 2,libro_completo =0;
```

I store jpg files in /var/lib/mysql-files/ so mysql can import it.